# What it means when the stainless steel shaft gets rusted?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I received a stainless steel shaft to install on a vertical centrifugal machine.

I postponed the job for three weeks and after that I found rust on most of the surface. I guess that I received a 304L SS.

The original shaft stands spotless and shining. Because the centrifuge turns at 6000 rpm does this observation means something about the mechanical properties of the shaft?

It seems that I received a different stainless steel. Also, although the diameter at the position of bearings is same the restribution of mass all along the shaft is quite different comparing with the original. Could I trust this shaft?

Comment: It was likely on contact at some point with carbon steel that ate away it’s corrosion layer (which is a self healing/self protecting layer of stainless steels in general) in spots for long periods (or worked on with tools that had carbon steels impregnated in them, which were then impregnated into the shaft, causing your rust spots, which ofc continues to spread over a long period of time…i assume you didn’t just leave the shaft sitting around in dirty rusty water?

Comment: @morbo it was kept in a dry place. Does this mean that the material is inferior so that I must not use the shaft?

Comment: no certainly not. It will forever rust however, until you treat the surface to get rid of the rust

Comment: @morbo thank you

Comment: the rust may run deep, just so you know, if the part came from a machine shop, i would consider talking to them to find out what they did, especially if the part should be completely rust free!

Answer (score 3):

No stainless should rust in dry storage for a few weeks. Presumably a shaft has a machined surface so imbeded steel grit from blast cleaning is not a possibility ( a fairly old, common problem).  Even carbon steel should resist rusting in a dry interior storage. 304 SS would be non-magnetic. What is "mass redistribution" ? In a location of high humidity, like a seacoast, moisture can condense with temperature changes and cause rust of carbon steel contamination on stainless. Actually, in a sea coast location, moisture and salt could even cause surface rust on a stainless.